# Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key,

Tags: react-native

I'm getting the following error Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key,

When using React Native, listview

here is my code

```
// Render the row for the list view
    _renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight underlayColor={'#ccc'} onPress={() => this._onPressProject({projectName:rowID.projectName, projectId:rowID.projectId})}>
                <View>
                    <View style={styles.row}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>{rowID.projectName}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `key` prop of the component you put in every row.
Could probably work with that `projectId` you have there like this:

```
_renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight key={rowID.projectId} underlayColor={'#ccc'} onPress={() => this._onPressProject({projectName:rowID.projectName, projectId:rowID.projectId})}>
            <View>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{rowID.projectName}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );
}
```

Comment: I did that I tried both the TouchableHighlight and view and text still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `key` whenever looping through some element to be rendered. Each `key` should be unique.

A "key" is a special string attribute you need to include when creating lists of elements.

You can read more about [key from documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Answer (score 0):

So this had nothing to do with list view render row but the following JS code, not really sure why I should be able to push an object into an array

```
for(j = 0; j < projectLength; j++) {
                project = projects[j];
                // Add Unique Row ID to RowID Array for Section
                rowIDs[i].push({proejctName:project.name. projectId:project.id});

                // Set Value for unique Section+Row Identifier that will be retrieved by getRowData
                dataBlob[company.id + ':' + project.id] = project;
            }
```

I fixed but just doing the following

```
rowIDs[i].push(project.name + ':' + project.id);
```